# I converted a c++ vector data-set into a c array. I pass the same data-set into a function that should give the same output

Tags: c++, c, cblas

This code should generate the same output. But the c output seems to be rounded up while c++ is not. I don't understand what is going on here. 
Please explain.

Upto the point where I show the code, same values are passed to both c and c++ code.

c code:

```
unsigned int sz1=sz+1; 
double* bMat = (double*)calloc(bMatSize,bMatSize * sizeof(double));

for (unsigned int ii = 0; ii<sz; ii++)
    for (unsigned int jj = 0; jj <= ii; jj++)
    {
       bMat[jj*sz1 + ii] = simgms_math_ddot(numBFunc, queueTest[ii], queueTest[jj] );
       bMat[ii*sz1 + jj] = bMat[jj*sz1 + ii];
    }
```

c++ code:

```
std::vector<double> bMat;
unsigned int sz1=sz+1;
bMat.resize(sz1*sz1);
for(unsigned int ii=0; ii<sz; ii++)
    for(unsigned int jj=0; jj<=ii; jj++)
    {
        bMat.at(jj*sz1+ii)=simgms_math_ddot(numBFunc, queueTest.at(ii).data(), queueTest.at(jj).data());
        bMat.at(ii*sz1+jj)=bMat.at(jj*sz1+ii);
    }

for (int i = 0; i < bMat.size(); ++i) {
   std::cout << bMat[i] << ' ';
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

common function

```
double simgms_math_ddot(unsigned int numElements, double aMat[], double bMat[])

{
    const MKL_INT n=numElements;

    double res = cblas_ddot(n, aMat, 1, bMat, 1);

    return res;
}
```

c coutput (bMat)

```
0 0 -1 0 0 -1 -1 -1 0
```

c++ coutput (bMat)

```
 1.05e-05 0.00134 -1 0.00134 1.11 -1 -1 -1 0
```

And the error matrix contains values:

```
1.78e-15 0.387 1.3 -0.48 -17.5 2.28 -0.387 -1.78e-15 1.48 -0.33 -17.3 2.4 -1.3 -1.48 -1.11e-16 1.08 -0.926 2.41 0.48 0.33 -1.08 0 0.551 0.74 17.5 17.3 0.926 -0.551 0 -0.384 -2.28 -2.4 -2.41 -0.74 0.384 0

std::deque< double* > queueTest;
```

....Its filled with errorMatrix elements, which are 2d arrays,

```
 e.g: queueTest.push_front(errorMatrix);
```

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C!

Comment: how do you print your result on the C side? if your `printf` format is wrong, that would explain a lot.

Comment: @Olaf don't shoot the guy: he's using `vector` in C++ instead of `new`, that's a good start!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: How is your comment in any way related to mine?

Comment: @Olaf: Your sentence was in the imperative and included an exclamation mark! Which might be interpreted as shouting! You see?!

Comment: @Olaf don't take it the wrong way. I was just pointing out that OP uses correct C++ code. And casting the return of `malloc` in C is not a very serious offence, it's just useless.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but I can't see how this is printed in the C version

Comment: @4386427 exactly, and that's probably the key of the difference.

Comment: As in *there's literally no code that outputs anything*? Well, yeah. Must be missing :)

Comment: I have the code in an 'extern c'. So I still use c++ std::cout to print. So its the same code that I use to print in c++

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre for (unsigned int i = 0; i < bMatSize; ++i) {
     std::cout << bMat[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre not *just useless*, I think it is *a bit* harmful in that it makes casting of pointer types look like a normal thing to do. But indeed, nothing to "shout" about ;)

Comment: where is `queueTest` defined/allocated in the C version? also does  `simgms_math_ddot` has a valid prototype in the C version?

Comment: note that it's not just rounded. Some values don't match their rounded counterparts (ex: 1.11 vs 0)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Such caasts can shadow errors, e.g. typos or missing headers. It is very well considered harmful. It also is a good indicator if the code is **really** compiled with a C compiler or not. There are way too many people thinking compiling C coding style with a C++ compiler is identical to C code.  Oh, and shouting is more LIKE THIS!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre std::deque< double* > queueTest; ....Its filled with errorMatrix elements, which are 2d arrays, e.g:  queueTest.push_front(errorMatrix);

Comment: @einpoklum: The Exclamation mark just adds some emphasis to the sentence. Shouting would be ALL UPPERCASE.

Comment: And the error matrix contains values,                                                                         ,1.78e-15 0.387 1.3 -0.48 -17.5 2.28 -0.387 -1.78e-15 1.48 -0.33 -17.3 2.4 -1.3 -1.48 -1.11e-16 1.08 -0.926 2.41 0.48 0.33 -1.08 0 0.551 0.74 17.5 17.3 0.926 -0.551 0 -0.384 -2.28 -2.4 -2.41 -0.74 0.384 0

Comment: @MadHatter - Don't put information in comments - update the question using the `edit` link just below the question

Comment: @4386427 put "edit" between square brackets to provide the [edit] link.

Comment: @MadHatter correct me if I'm wrong, but a double ended queue isn't contiguous in memory. So in C it will fail.

Comment: @4386427: like this `[edit]`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably because of the way you're storing `queueTest` in a `deque`.

```
queueTest.at(ii).data()
```

reaches the iith element without problem (but with `O(n)` complexity, and can make you think that it's indexed access whereas it's not), but if you pass the address of the first element of the `std::deque` to your C program, adding an offset won't work because, unlike `std::vector` memory, `std::deque` memory isn't contiguous (it's a linked list) so you're getting random data for your coefficients.

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/:

> unlike vectors, deques are not guaranteed to store all its elements in contiguous storage locations: accessing elements in a deque by offsetting a pointer to another element causes **undefined behavior**.

The quickfix to be able to use it from the C side is to convert your `deque` to a `vector`.

Comment: I'll try this and get back to you, thanks!